# Pass data between view controllers in navigation controller

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

So I have a Navigation Controller together with 2 view controllers. The first view controller shows a text label with some text in it, a text field to type in a list of ingredients for food and a button that should bring us to our second view controller that will make a list out of the input in the text field. The following code is for the first view controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var foodImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchField: UITextField!

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "goSegue"){
        if (searchField.text != ""){
            let listOfFood = segue.destination as! ListOfFoodViewController
            listOfFood.commaString = searchField.text!
        }
        else if (searchField.text == ""){
            let alertEmpty = UIAlertController(title: "Emptyness", message: "There is no input!", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Understood", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alertEmpty.addAction(defaultAction)
            self.present(alertEmpty, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

In the storyboard I made a segue (which I called "goSegue") to the second view controller (which is called ListOfFoodViewController) using the button. My code for the second view controller is

```
import UIKit

class ListOfFoodViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
var commaString = ""
var listOfTags = [String]()
let simpleTableIdentifier = "SimpleTableIdentifier"

//DATA SOURCE METHODS
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return listOfTags.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: simpleTableIdentifier)
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: simpleTableIdentifier)
    }
    cell?.textLabel?.text=listOfTags[indexPath.row]
    return cell!
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.commaString = ""
    self.listOfTags = self.commaString.components(separatedBy: ",")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

So the user has to input a comma separated list of words, and I make a listOfTags out of it and I put this in the table. So before the segue, the function prepare(for segue ...) should be called and in here I make an instance of my second view controller (which has a property commaString) and assign the input to commaString as follows

```
let listOfFood = segue.destination as! ListOfFoodViewController
listOfFood.commaString = searchField.text!
```

But when I run this program, everything works except that the tableview is empty! I do not know why does this not work. Does it have something to do with the fact that I am using a Navigation Controller?

Comment: As the start of `viewDidLoad()`, you do `self.commaString = ""`. Aren't you then deleting the previous value you set? Then, just afterwards, you read it. How is that supposed to work? What about writing a `didSet()` on `commaString` and when it's called, create `listOfTags`?

Comment: You need to reload tableView after you've assigned a new value to your listOfTags array. In your viewDidLoad, right after this line self.listOfTags = self.commaString.components(separatedBy: ",") put this code: self.tableView.reloadData()

Answer (score 1):

This is because you clear it here in `viewDidLoad`

```
 self.commaString = ""
```

so  comment that line and  declare commaString like this

```
var commaString = "" {
  didSet {
      self.listOfTags = self.commaString.components(separatedBy: ",")
  }

}
```

//

```
self.tableView.delegate = self
self.tableView.dataSource = self
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. However after I edited my code, it still displays nothing in the tableview. What is going on?

Comment: Did you commented the line and verified that the sended string is not nil ?? try to print it inside prepareForSegue before assignment ,  also make sure to connect the segue to the VC no to a button

Comment: you also need to set delegate and dataSource of the table in viewDidLoad

Comment: yes I commented that line and also I printed the searchField.text in the prepare function. The string is not nil as it got printed what I typed. About the segue: I have a button in the first view controller and I controll-dragged from this button to the second VC and set action to show.

Comment: how do I set delegate and datasource of the table in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Ok my bad, changed it but still no succes.

Comment: It seems like searchField.text is not being passed, if I print self.commaString in the second VC in the viewDidLoad method, it prints nothing.

Comment: connect the source of the segue to the VC not to the clicked button

Answer (score 0):

In ViewController, you are saying:

```
listOfFood.commaString = searchField.text!
```

In ListOfFoodViewController, you are saying:

```
self.commaString = ""
```

So whatever ViewController put into ListOfFoodViewController, ListOfFoodViewController immediately erases it, and we end up with an empty table.